# How to select variables in R from NHANES dataset to fit a logistic regression?

Tags: r, regression, logistic, feature-selection

I need to fit a logistic regression of the NHANES dataset available in R. It has 76 variables in it but I have been able to filter it to 40 variables by removing NA columns. I still need to select the best variable out of these 40. Is there any way to conduct this variable selection in R in a simple way?

Comment: You need to tell us in which package you found `NHANES`

Comment: And why you would use a statistical technique now known to be invalid.  Formulate a question of interest, then specify a model.  Don't play around with statistically-based variable selection.  Select variables according to subject matter expertise.  If some of the variables are "insignificant" you know you're doing it right.  Be sure to use one of the existing R NHANES packages. Deal with NAs in a principled way.